# Hive create table from another table and store format as parquet

Tags: sql, presto

when i try to run this hive query:

```
create table my_db.test_table
as (select * from my_db.my_table
where partition_date >= '2019-06-01')
STORED as PARQUET;
```

I am seeing the error:

```
SQL Error [1]: Query failed (#1): line 5:1: mismatched 
    input 'STORED' expecting {<EOF>, 'EXCEPT', 'INTERSECT', 
'LIMIT', 'ORDER', 'UNION', 'WITH'}
```

Does this have anything to do with the fact that `my_db.my_table` is in `RCBINARY` format? or that it is not understanding what `stored as` means?

If die to `RCBINARY`, how do i convert from `RCBINARY`format to `PARQUET`?

Answer (score 2):

I realized that this is a presto DB and not a Hive question.

This worked for me:

```
create table my_db.test_table
WITH (format = 'PARQUET')
as (select * from my_db.my_table
where partition_date >= '2019-06-01');
```